# How to Improve WooCommerce Product Category Thumbnail Quality?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, image-scaling, image-quality

I’m currently in the process of setting up the Botiga theme and have come across a little hiccup. My product category thumbnails aren’t as crisp as I’d like them to be. However, the individual product images look great, since they’re using the original, high-resolution image.

It seems that the thumbnails are using a 420×420 scaled-down version of the original, which might be causing them to appear a bit blurry. Does anyone have any advice on how to adjust the settings so that the original, clearer image is used for these thumbnails?

I use the free version of the Botiga Theme.

http://test.studio-karamelo.de/blumenpresse/

- I tried the regenerative Thumbnails Plugin, that made it worse.
- I changed the Imagesize under Settings > Media, but nothing happened.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try to add the following, to get the full size on product category thumbnails :

```
add_filter( 'subcategory_archive_thumbnail_size', function(){return 'full';});
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It could work.